# How to "Find" looked up data

Tags: excel

So when you have data that are looked up from another table, for example NAMES using vlookup, when you try to use the "Find" function and look for a specific name, it fails to yield any result since it's vlookup formula in the cell instead of the value of the data from another table. Is there anyway to find the original value that we want?

Comment: Finding something on the result set of vlookup or finding result of vlookup in some string. Both works fine. Can you give example of your problem?

Comment: We have training records in excel. The names are looked up from our employee details. For example, the name Rebecca is looked up using "index match" function. So, when I ctrl+find , and type in Rebecca, no result is found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you press Ctrl+find, click on the "Options >>" button.
And the select "Values" from the "Look In" drop down. Then you should be able to find the value.

Comment: Okay I'm being stupid for not noticing it. Thank you mate!